# send message by discordpy to a channel within a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, discord, warnings, sendmessage

I have the script below, in which I want to send message discord channel everytime I go into IF. Discord sends messages to the channel within loop (so it is actually working), but I do receive some errors and warnings within while loop waiting to enter the IF again (I am supposed to enter the IF every 60 seconds).

here the body of my script:

```
import discord
import asyncio

TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
channel_id = 111111111111111111111111

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
    await send_message_in_loop()

async def send_message_in_loop():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    while True:
        try:
        
            while True:
                
                # ==================================================
                # DOING SOME STUFF HERE INCDLUGING SOME "time.sleep"
                # ==================================================
                
                passedTime=SERVERTIME # the server time is being updated by server API
                
                # I want to enter the loop when the seconds of the server time are within 3 to 6
                if (passedTime)>3 and (passedTime)<6:
                    
                    # ==================================================
                    # DOING SOME STUFF HERE INCDLUGING SOME "time.sleep"
                    # ==================================================
                    
                    message='last check: '+str(SERVERTIME)
                    task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(channel.send(message))
                    await asyncio.gather(task)
                    await asyncio.sleep(5)
                    
        except:
                print('repeat')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

the error is as below:

```
ERROR    discord.client Attempting a reconnect in 0.59s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lt13485\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", 
line 659, in connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\lt13485\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 646, in poll_event
    raise ConnectionClosed(self.socket, shard_id=self.shard_id, code=code) from None
discord.errors.ConnectionClosed: Shard ID None WebSocket closed with 1000
```

I also receive warning as below:

```
WARNING  discord.gateway Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
```

I do appreciate any help about this!

I actually expect to not receive errors in my terminal, as I am printing already some stuff there

Answer (score 1):

Your client is getting stucked in the while True loop, ence your error because it can't update it's database, nor try to reconnect or do other things.

Essentially, you are blocking discord threads inside your while loop, which you shouldn't

To achieve what you are trying to do, you should use a function in discord api that allows you to call a function every X second

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5) // your timer
async def send_message_in_loop():
         enter code here
```

Additionally, you need to tell discord to launch this function

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    send_message_in_loop.start()
```

Comment: I've already tried it, it gives still the same error and warning repeateadly, eventhough it works and sends message to channel.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! In my bot, I handle timed loops with the `@tasks.loop` decorator:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks
import discord

@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0, count=5) # get rid of count=5 for an infinite loop
async def slow_count():
    print(slow_count.current_loop)

@slow_count.after_loop
async def after_slow_count():
    print('done!')
```

I think this is the standard for doing it, it could be acting weird for you because they built the API to work like this.

Comment: thanks for your reply!

can you please tell me where I can locate the functions that you've mentioned? I am kind of new to Python, so that looks a bit complicated for me!

Thanks

Comment: @Neuroscientist The `tasks` decorator is located in `discord.ext`, and you can gain access to it in your program by adding the `from discord import tasks` line at the very top of your code, with your other imports. For more info on decorators: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator, for more info on `import`: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/import-module-python/ Good luck on your journey learning Python, have fun.

Comment: actually this is not working either as I tried.

maybe one alternative can be to turn off the warnings and error messages send by discord.

do you have any idea about how it can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: @Neuroscientist I would advise against turning off the warnings, they're likely happening because of Discord's own inner processes being interrupted as Sparkling Marcel described. If there's any way you could post a minimal reproducible example it would help in solving your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import time

token = 'XXXXXX'
channel = 11111111111111

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
@bot.event
async  def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('bot in active')

@tasks.loop(seconds=2)
async def change_status():
    group_channel = bot.get_channel(channel)
    await group_channel.send('here')
    time.sleep(90)
bot.run(token)

Comment: the code above is what I am exactly using, just need to replace a token and channel then it should work and you'll see what is the actual problem

Comment: @Neuroscientist `time.sleep` doesn't work in asynchronous functions. Also, instead of using `time.sleep`, you should change `seconds=2` to `seconds=90`. Delete `time.sleep(90)`, replace `seconds=2` with `seconds=90`, and your code should be okay, lmk what happens.

Comment: removing the time.sleep and changing the seconds, removed the errors and is working nice, but the point is the "time.sleep" that I have place in code, is to resemble the other tasks being done within the async def (the task includes some calculations and time.sleep).

Comment: @Neuroscientist In that case, you should be able to run a `time.sleep(90)` in an async with `await asyncio.sleep(90)`.

Comment: if this `await asyncio.sleep(90)` is just supposed to stop the the `await group_channel.send(message)`, is not doing so and is blocking my loop.. ;(

Comment: @Neuroscientist I'm not sure I understand what you mean, your loop should be unblocked by the time the 90 seconds go by. What is the exact behavior that you are looking for?

Comment: I have a while loop, which is being updated every seconds. within this while loop, there is a IF condition in which every 60 seconds the code goes into it, does some calculations, then at the end I want to send a message to my channel (e.g. task done), and go back to the while loop (which await asyncio blocks the code actually)

Comment: Hello Neuroscientist, that seem like a new question and I think you should make a new post since now it's not about the bug anymore but about some algorithm logic :)
Don't forget to put the updated code in here as well, and maybe a link to the new thread in comment here

Comment: I have modified the question here. maybe it is more clear now

Comment: @SparklingMarcel I have created another thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76150238/continuosly-receiving-warnings-while-send-message-in-using-discordpy-within-whil

Comment: Sweet, don't forget to mark your prefered response as an answer to this thread.
Also, in the new thread you didn't apply the advice you got here, essentially repeating the same thread as this one and getting error for the same reason.