# continuosly receiving warnings while send message in using discordpy within while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, discord, warnings

I have the script below, in which I am using to send message to a discord channel using a bot. This scripts works well, meaning that sends message everytime we enter to IF function, but meanwhile within WHILE loop, I receives continously warnings and errors as brought below.

Any help is appreciated to solve the warning and error messages.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import time

# DISCORD logging in 
TOKEN = 'asdasdasdasd'
channel_id = 1111111

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
    await send_message_in_loop()

async def send_message_in_loop():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    while True:
        # ==================================================
        # DOING SOME STUFF HERE INCDLUGING SOME "time.sleep"
        # ==================================================
        sec = datetime.utcnow().second        
        print(sec)
        
        # I want to enter the loop every 60 seconds
        if sec==0:
            # ==================================================
            # DOING SOME STUFF HERE INCDLUGING SOME "time.sleep"
            # ==================================================
            
            message='last check: '+str(sec)
            task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(channel.send(message))
            await asyncio.gather(task)

        time.sleep(1)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

WARNING MESSAGE:

```
WARNING  discord.gateway Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
ERROR    discord.client Attempting a reconnect in 3.99s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lt13485\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", 
line 659, in connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\lt13485\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 646, in poll_event
    raise ConnectionClosed(self.socket, shard_id=self.shard_id, code=code) from None
discord.errors.ConnectionClosed: Shard ID None WebSocket closed with 1000
```

I am trying to remove the warning and error messages being printer in TERMINAL.

Answer (score 0):

import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

It would suppress all warnings so be careful.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I've already tried this and it doesn't work